# Backup SQL DATABASE with C# 3.0

Tags: c#, sql-server

How do u backup SQL Server db with C# 3.0 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't - C# is a programming language and as such is unsuitable for database maintenance.  The *.NET Framework* has an API that will allow you to work with a SQL Server database but even this is not the best way to do database maintenance.

SQL Server has a rich array of tools that can be used for backing up a database.  Please see these links for more information:

- [Backup Overview (SQL Server)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175477.aspx)
- [How to: Back Up a Database (SQL Server Management Studio)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187510.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

You can use SQL SMO to backup the database and perform other SQL functions through c#.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can call the "BACKUP DATABASE" SQL command using a SQL Command Object.  You should be able to find some documentation but here is some basic syntax I found

**Example**

```
BACKUP DATABASE [Master] TO  [MasterDevice] WITH  
RETAINDAYS = 5, NOFORMAT, INIT,  NAME = N'Master-FullBackup', SKIP, NOREWIND, 
NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
GO
```

**Syntax** 
    BACKUP DATABASE {database_name | @database_name_var}
    TO  [,...n]
    [WITH 
        [BLOCKSIZE = {blocksize | @blocksize_variable}]
        [[,] DESCRIPTION = {text | @text_variable}]
        [[,] DIFFERENTIAL]
        [[,] EXPIREDATE = {date | @date_var} 
            | RETAINDAYS = {days | @days_var}]
        [[,] FORMAT | NOFORMAT]
        [[,] {INIT | NOINIT}]
        [[,] MEDIADESCRIPTION = {text | @text_variable}]
        [[,] MEDIANAME = {media_name | @media_name_variable}]
        [[,] [NAME = {backup_set_name | @backup_set_name_var}]
        [[,] {NOSKIP | SKIP}]
        [[,] {NOUNLOAD | UNLOAD}]
        [[,] [RESTART]
        [[,] STATS [= percentage]]
    ]

Answer (score 0):

by executing a backup database command, but this has nothing to do with C#